# Pdf on client side, multi language, and utf8

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, java-8, itext

I am working on generating a pdf browser side.

Initially I used jspdf but it failed to support utf8 and unicode characters.

My data which has to be written in pdf could be in multiple languages, any possible language in world.

Is there any possible way to achieve this or I have to generate a pdf on the server using Java.

Comment: You have already tagged iText. What you want to do, can be done with iText. So yes there is a possible way and you have already given the answer yourself. Do you *have* to do it server side? I don't know all the features of jspdf so I cannot answer your question.

Comment: Does itext support all possible languages and characters .And will it able to add and decided which do to use automatically

Comment: saying `failed to support utf8 and unicode characters` it's like saying nothing. *what exactly* is not working for you or what *exact characters* you found un-supported?